# How to use ScrollView and ContainerView with Autolayout checked

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, ios7, xcode5

I have trouble implementing scrollview with auto layout:/

Here is simple "Hello World" project with that problem: http://www.sendspace.com/file/cg96by

But the problem… I need to create scrollview, but also I need to use auto layout. So I created pure single view application, added (like I saw in some tutorials) Scrollview (the same size as main view), added constraints (all zeros) and then add Container View (the same size as scroll view), add constraints and.. It's didn't work:/ It doesn't scroll. Here is the screen of that situation: 
[image]

Now, when I delete two constraints named: Center X and Y Alignment (marked on the screen), it works perfectly, but Xcode5 doesn't quite like it :/ and shows some errors like on the next screen below.

Why does he want width and heigh 0 ?!

Actually ContainerView doesn't matter. I've also tried with image view. When you select "Add missing constraints" it also add Center X and Y Alignment. And scroll doesn't work. When you delete them, scroll works but you have this warring:

[image]

Comment: do you intend to have a container in the scrollview? I would imagine the container is completely unnecessary here, Im not sure if you understand how to use it or need it in this case, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to have scroll view and use auto layout

edit. I was following this article: http://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/ios-how-to-use-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-pure-auto-layout/

Comment: ok well why not just put the scrollview right inside of the view, instead of using a container? and then use autolayout for the height and width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I find manually adding the autolayout constraints to be quite confusing, using the "Add New Constraints" button at the bottom really comes in handy, try this, after you get each view where you want it use that way of adding layout constraints for each view (ie scrollView, containerView, UIImageView) I did this, and heres the example, select each constraint as I have so that the top, left, bottom, and right edges are set, this should do exactly what you want.

You will probably want to erase all your current constraints and then implement them this way.

heres the layout like you want http://cl.ly/image/463k2043401L

and heres the example adding the constraints: http://cl.ly/image/472l2V0l3N1L

To keep it dynamic so that you can rotate it, you will want to do the above for all view BUT the container view... then If you control drag from container to scrollview with no constraints, you can add all of them that it suggests except for the height and width at the bottom, that satisfies any missing constraints and should do the trick, It will center the container inside of the scrollview and keep it pinned to the top, bottom, left and right, and it should dynamically change with your scrollview content size.

http://cl.ly/image/1o3k1e452W0g

Sorry for the confusion, hope this helps!

Comment: So, you suggest to replace Center X and Y Alignment with Width and Height… but then width is fixed. And when user will rotate iPhone left - width still will be 320px.. I'm not sure about that

Comment: OK, I got it! You have to add constraints:
Top, bottom, left, right and height (has to be fixed) but no width (cause then your view will not resize after rotate). And then add Center X (only) Alignment. That works perfect for me. Thanks:)

Comment: I was actually going to edit my answer, you can exclude fixing the height and width on the container.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and i found relative simple solution from within Interface Builder using pure Autolayout without any code.

For proof-of-concept at first remove any constraint in View Controller to if see this works.

This is sample layout:

- View (main view of my UIViewController)

  - Scroll View (UIScrollView)

    - Container View (UIView)

      - Content View (e.g. UIImageView)

A. Scroll View width/height should be smaller that Container View width/height

B. Container View should have some determinated width/height (may be explicit width/height )

C. Do Control-drag Container View to Scroll View and add only:

1. Leading Space to Container
2. Trailing Space to Container

D. Check out those two constraints and set "constant" value for both to 0

E. Run app and